# Barcode not working on Crystal Server 2011

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008, crystal-reports-server

We just setup a Crystal Server 2011, and we can't get the barcode font to work. We installed the barcode font on our server, but when we run the barcode doesn't show up.

Is there any setting we missed?

Do we have to add the font to the Crystal Server 2011?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The barcode was actually working, we just didn't see the barcode, because I printed one of the documents and it worked. I then realized that it was just how we were viewing it. I enabled Active X and it now shows up in the internet browser.